# Data Visualization Help

Tags: visualization

I am needing help with modeling some data to see if there is a correlation between two variables.  I am wanting to know what would be the best math model to use to analyze the data.  Right now, I am leaning toward developing a linear regression model and create some type of Histogram.  I’m curious to know if anyone had a better suggestion to visualize the data.

Essentially, I am comparing the day of week to an approximate time value by the hour such as 1 p.m.  I have a total of approximately 2400 observations.